# How should the bounds of decimal and degree coordinates be programmatically handled in respect to hemispheres?

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, extents, standards

Are the bounds inclusive of 0, 90/180?

Many systems and libraries simply clamp it to from -n to +n without considering zero. In many of these cases the handling of 0 is arbitrary (which hemisphere it lands on for example). In other cases -0 is supported (which offers more even distribution).

Some descriptions suggest that 0 doesn't really exist, values simply move closer to it but never reach it, however some implementations include 0.

If it's down to the person implementing the system which system is preferred?

1. 0 < n < max
2. 0 <= n < max
3. 0 < n <= max
4. 0 <= n <= max

Given the even options should 0 be negative or fall on a specific hemisphere?

I can't answer my own question as it's locked...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

From a programming perspective, standards wise signed zero is an anomaly, it is an artifact that is often ignored and not supported directly by programming languages. It's also mathematically broken. The different between -0 and 0 is still 0.

An algorithm wont care about human representation and segments.

Given a coordinate in the range -90 to 90, it will most likely have 90 added to it and then possible another 180 depending on hemisphere.

Thus simplifying things to two values of 0..360 (an internal representation simplifed as much as possible, removing the sign entirely would be preferable for machine use) starting at point 0. As far as the machine is concerned there are no such thing as hemispheres, it is a presentation concern.

This does still become a problem for humans, where which hemisphere 0 lands on is still arbitrary.

Problems can also arise where machines talk to one another using coordinate systems then contain a format intended for humans (they specify hemisphere).

However it's very unlikely for something to land exactly on 0,0 and the precision loss is usually so small that it very rarely, almost never, manifests as a real problem. Many systems will add some extra precision to either eliminate the problem by isolating it to within a tiny fragment of least significance or to slow it's accumulation.

Whatever method is used involving hemispheres, it should be well defined enough to convert both ways without precision loss (such as > being used for output but < on input).

Hemisphere replaces the sign. As it makes no sense for coordinates of exactly zero, the obvious option is to leave it out. As with the floating point representation, it's an artifact that can be ignored.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question (+1). Although someone has voted to close as too broad (probably because it has 3 questions) common sense suggests a useful answer could address all points without needing to deviate at all from the main subject (i.e. what is the standard, if any?). Imagine if Q was split in 3 questions; the content would be fragmented making it difficult for us readers to search and get the big picture about the standard.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is a multiple answer question, either covering one of the possibilities I've brought up or alternatively something I've missed (including who implements, etc). It's broad because rather than asking about a specific system, I would like to know in general, for any major system that might be known of. The questions are really being concise about what I'd like to know in particular about the bounds handling for any given standard.

Comment: You also have to think about storage, processing, and display. -0 is probably fine for storage or processing, but might look weird if displayed. Processing could send values over n--do you immediately force them to n? Why are you leaving out negatives? Longitude can run -360 to 0, -180 to +180 or 0 to 360. Laittude is -90 to 90.

Comment: I agree, I think this is an important question.  It should be researched, considered, discussed and answered.

Comment: I think you don't need to care about this. Coordinate 0,0 is at sea. By tide, derivation and wind movements you will never be at 0,0 and always fall in some hemisphere. Jokes apart, I think will be correct to say `0º 0' 0'' N` or  `0º 0' 0'' S`

Comment: @flurbius This site really isn't the place for all that though.

Comment: There are basically no use cases where this will ever be a problem.  Statistically the chances of ever having to work with a coordinate positioned directly at (0,0) that this question really isn't worthy considering.  And because coordinate values almost always contain a large number of sig figs, you're much more likely to have something like (0.000001, 0.000001) etc.  This is like the ultimate "what if" question that doesn't really add value to anything and isn't worth much consideration from a fundamental GIS perspective.

Comment: @onakua that might be in the ideal world but in the real world occasionally things might surprise you. The chances are for example higher than you might appreciate as the problem might occur in (0,n) or (n,0) rather than only (0,0). Another thing that can be problematic is that sometimes people don't use a high precision. However I do believe I've solved the problem if you look at the edit on my answer. In any case it is unlikely to be a problem but it's not necessarily as impossibly unlikely as for example a 128bit hash collision and if you can have more accuracy/precision then you should.